# Should k-means input contain unique values or all values (repeated as well)?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am clustering my single dimensional data with a kmeans implementation. Although there are methods like Jenks breaks and Fishers's natural breaks for single dimensional data I still chose to go with kmeans.

My question is what difference does it make if I only cluster unique values in the list of data points I have OR if I use all data points (repetition).

What is advisable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can certainly make a difference: the mean of [-1 -1 1] is -.33, while the mean of [-1 1] is 0. What you should do depends on the data and what you want to do with the result of clustering. As a default, though, I'd say keep them: removing points changes the local densities that *k*-means is designed to pick as cluster centers, and also why would you remove duplicates, but not near-duplicates?

Comment: I need to cluster closer values together in the clusters. Intuitively, I was thinking that clustering is concerned with putting 'unique' points which are close enough together. It looks like it is density based as well.

Comment: @ManojAwasthi k-means is very much density-based, other methods not necessarily.

Answer (score 0):

*k*-means is an optimization method which minimizes the *distortion* of an assignment of your data points into clusters. The distortion is the sum of within cluster sum of squares. Or, if `L` is a set of labels and `P` the set of points, if `has` indicates that a point has a particular label, and `d` is the distance between points, then

```
distortion = sum [ d(p1, p2)^2 | p1 <- P
                               , p2 <- P
                               , l  <- L
                               , p1 has l and p2 has l 
                               ]
```

We can study the result of a successful *k*-means optimization by talking about this distortion. For instance, given any two points on top of one another we have the distance between them `d(p1, p2) = 0` and so if they're in the same cluster then they are increasing the distortion by nothing at all. So, somewhat obviously, a good clustering will always have all point duplicates in the same cluster.

Now consider a set of 3 points like this

```
   A          ?          B
---p----------q----------r---
```

In other words, three equidistant points, the two on the outside of different labels and the one on the inside of an unknown label. The distances (measured in `-`es) are `d(p,q) = 10 = d(q,r)` so if we label `q` as `A` we increase our distortion by 100 and same if we label it `B`.

If we change this situation slightly by replicating the point `p` then we've not increased the distortion at all (since `d(p,s) = 0`) but labeling `q has A` then we'll increase the distortion by `d(p,q)^2 + d(s,q)^2 = 100 + 100 = 200` while if we label it `q has B` then the distortion increases only by `d(q,r)^2 = 100`.

```
   A          ?          B
---p----------q----------r---
   s
```

So this replication has repulsed `q` away from label `A`.

---

Now if you play around with *k*-means for a bit, you might be surprised by the analysis above. It'll turn out to be the case that adding a whole lot of replication of a single point won't really produce the linearly scaling impact it seems like it ought to.

This is because actual optimization of that metric is known to be NP-hard in almost any circumstance. If you truly want to optimize it and have `n` points with `K` labels then your best bet is to check all `K^n` labelings. Thus, most *k*-means algorithms are approximate and thus you suffer some *search error* between the true optimum and the result of your algorithm.

For *k*-means, this will be happen especially when there are lots of replicated points as these "replicated pools" still grab points according to their distance from the centroid... not actually due to their global minimization properties.

---

Finally, when talking about replication in machine learning algorithms it's worth noting that most machine learning algorithms are based on assumptions about data which actively preclude the idea of replicated data points. This is known broadly as "general position" and many proofs begin by assuming your data is in "general position".

The idea is that if your points are truly distributed in `R^n` then there's 0 probability that two points will be identical under any of the probability distributions which are "nice" enough to build algorithms atop.

What this generally means is that if you have data with a lot of replicated points, you should consider the impact of a small "smoothing" step prior to analysis. If perturbing all of your points by a small normally distributed jump does not affect the meaning of the data... then you're probably quite OK running normal ML algorithms that anticipate the data living in `R^n`. If not, then you should consider algorithms which better respect the structure of your data—perhaps it's better to see your data as a tree and run an algorithm for ML atop structured data.